# I am getting an error when i don`t set the radio button

Tags: php

I try to do some conditions and when i set the text filed and not the radio button i will get a php error.
..........................................................................................................................................

This is my code:

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="text" name="name">
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other">Other
   <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php

   $name = $nameErr = $gender = $genderErr = '';

   if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

       if ($_POST['name'] == '' || $_POST['gender'] == '') {
          echo('all filed');
       }
       else {

          if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
             $nameErr = "Name is required";
          } else {
             $name = $_POST["name"];
          }
          if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
             $genderErr = "Gender is required";
          } else {
             $gender = $_POST["gender"];
          }

       }

    }

  echo $name. ' ' .$gender;
?>
```

Comment: Please _always_ quote any error messages you get verbatim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
if ((isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'])  == '' || (isset($_POST['gender']) && $_POST['gender'] == '')) {
    echo('all filed');
}
```

you have to put the conditions if `$_POST['gender']` is set or not.
you can debug your code using :

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code please use condition below

```
if (isset($_POST["name"]) && $_POST["name"] != "") {
    $name = $_POST["name"];  
} else {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
}
if (isset($_POST["gender"]) && $_POST["gender"] != "") {
   $gender = $_POST["gender"];  
} else {
   $genderErr = "Gender is required";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing with wrong condition when checking the 'name' and 'gender' field. You've given 'OR (||)' in condition, so it means any of the field is empty it will return true the condition. Your condition is like:

```
if ($_POST['name'] == '' || $_POST['gender'] == '') {
    echo('all filed');
}
```

change it to :

```
 if ($_POST['name'] == '' && $_POST['gender'] == '') {
    echo('all filed');
 }
```

I hope your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

try with below code, the issue is you are trying to print value outside of the condition.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['gender'])) {
        echo('all filed');
    }
    else {

        if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
            $nameErr = "Name is required";
        }
        else {
            $name = $_POST["name"];
        }

        if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
            $genderErr = "Gender is required";
        }
        else {
            $gender = $_POST["gender"];
        }

        echo $name . ' ' . $gender;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

change this :

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="other">Other
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

to this :

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="radio" name="gender"  value="female" checked>Female
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="other">Other
<input type="submit">
</form>
```